# Update table in sql server, with values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

i have a table in sql server

```
id    count
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       1
```

i have another table in pandas dataframe(df), with updated count

```
id    count
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       3
5       4
```

i want to make changes in my database using Update query, and i am thinking to define a function, which would do this.

i am using pypyodbc for my connection.

```
    conn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=<YourServer>;Database=<YourDatabase>;uid=<YourUserName>;pwd=<YourPassword>"
```

i tried using

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    updateQuery = "update "+db_table+" set count="+str(row[1][1])+" where id= '"+str(row[1][0])+"'"
    cursor.execute(updateQuery)
    conn.commit()
```

But is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: So you are after a SQL Query here?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @iamdave yes, see edit

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in your question is an iterative update, looping through each row one by one.  SQL databases are very inefficient at this kind of operation.  SQL databases are *very* efficient at `set based` updates though.

What this means in practice, is write a script that can apply to the whole table in one go and then run it once.

In your case you can demonstrate this as follows in some volatile table variable from a query within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

First, create your test data:

```
declare @t table(id int, [count] int);
insert into @t values(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1);

declare @p table(id int, [count] int);
insert into @p values(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4);
```

The first two `select` statements show you what the data looks like before your update:

```
select *
from @t;

select *
from @p;
```

To update all your rows of data in your SQL Table, you can join it to the data that was in your Pandas table, and then `select` the data again so you can see the change that took place in the `update`:

```
update t
set [count] = p.[count]
from @t as t
    join @p as p
        on(t.id = p.id);

select *
from @t;

select *
from @p;
```

---

I am not too familiar with Pandas Dataframe so do not know exactly how you can access and query this data. If you are working on large datasets, I would recommend importing the Pandas data as is into a staging table in your SQL Server database and running the above type of query within SQL Server.